# SQL execute inner condition before outer condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

`SELECT * FROM (select * from VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS WHERE BRANCH = 'BR001') J WHERE ROW_NUM BETWEEN 1 AND 20`

Now, when I run the inner query, I have over 10,000 rows. The outer query, I'd expect, to limit the output of the inner query to 20.

If I run the entire query, I get 7 rows, even though I know I should get at least 20 rows.

Please advise on how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this SQL Server?, does `VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS` have a `ROW_NUM` column?

Comment: What is `ROW_NUM` in your query? Is it some identity column of `VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS`? And what is your goal - just to take any arbitrary 20 rows from inner query?

Comment: You tagged with SQL Server, but the usage of `ROW_NUM` looks like Oracle's `ROWNUM`...

Comment: Yeah, you were probably thinking of row_number(). But that's not directly usable from the `where` clause.

Comment: If it's SQL Server you can use `SELECT TOP (20)`

Comment: I get ROW_NUM expression by doing this **SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN 1) AS ROW_NUM FROM TABLE 1**

Comment: @kaybee99 Also, I can't use Top, because I want to parameterise the value, i.e. the user should enter the value to supply the top portion and my particular use case does not allow Top to be parameterised and supplied by a variable ;(

Comment: And ROW_NUM is definitely on VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS?

Comment: @kaybee99 It is, otherwise the query would return an error; see my comment above on how I achieved it

Comment: Out of interest, which 7 ROW_NUM values are returned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78554/discussion-between-stingray-and-kaybee99).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Oracle SQL, this should work:

```
select * from VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS 
where BRANCH = 'BR001' and rownum <= 20
```

Comment: No, it's MSSQL see my comment above on how I achieved the **ROW_NUM** value

Answer (score 0):

No need for a derived query. Just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_LARGE_ORDERS WHERE BRANCH = 'BR001' AND ROW_NUM <= 20
```

Comment: Tried this, it did not work, unfortunately; that's why I thought that if I put it inside the inner query, this could "force" SQL to execute the inner query first, which of course it does not.

Comment: Edit your original post with some sample data so I can see what's going on here.